# Amputated connected 2-point function is inverse to connected 2-point function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, greens-functions, propagator

Let $D_n$ denote the $n$-point correlation function consisting of only connected diagrams. We may decompose this as an integral of two products. The first factor consists of a product over the $n$ external legs and their corrections, each denoted $E^{(n)}_i$, so this factor becomes  $\prod_{i=1}^n E^{(n)}_i$. The second factor is the amputated diagrams which I will denote as $A_n$. In other words, $A_n$ are the diagrams that remain once the external legs and their corrections have been removed. Thus
$$D_n = \int 
\Big(\prod_{i=1} E^{(n)}_i\Big) A_n$$
where the integral is taken over all internal points.

With the above setup, I have read that the amputated 2-point correlation function is the inverse of the 2-point correlation function, i.e.
$$\int A_2 D_2 = \delta$$
but I can not see where this follows from.

Is there anyway to see why the amputated 2-point correlation function is the inverse to the 2-point (connected) correlation function without using effective actions?

Comment: Which lectures? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic These are lectures that have been shared with me so unfortunately they're not available online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Use the relations $$D_2~=~\int E_1A_2E_2\tag{1}$$ and
$$E_1~=~D_2~=~E_2\tag{2}$$ to conclude OP's sought-for relation
$$A_2~=~D_2^{-1}.\tag{3}$$

Eq. (2) can be argued in at least 2 ways:

1. Either we assume that the propagator $D_2$ is a matrix of *all* field species in the theory, and hence unique.
2. More commonly, we assume [or can prove e.g. via conservation laws] that the propagator $D_2$ is *diagonal* in the field species [so that there in principle are eqs. (1)-(3) for *each* field species].

Comment: For the first definition of $D_2$ you used, why can we omit the integrals and shouldn't we have $D_2 = E_1A_2E_2$? How do we know that $E_1 = E_2$?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to better understand Eq. (2). Wouldn't the external legs  $E_1$ or $E_2$ need to start at an external point and end at an internal point? If so, how could they be equal to $D_2$ which contains both external points?